# The name of theorem for integration where a variable can be moved out of the integration with a specific value

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[![The variable h as specific angular momentum is a function of r, while mass m=const. To simplify and to avoid h being integrated, a specific value of h (h-tilde) within the domain can be used to simplify the integration][1]][1]

As shown in the picture below, what is the theorem name for this operation, please? All variables are smooth and continuous in given domain. Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKDY7.png

Comment: This is an integral version of the mean value theorem.

Comment: [Linearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Properties) for $m$ (a constant).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you all! I will accept the "mean value theorem" answer. It is part of space-time motion study. The mass can vary with time too, but for now I just need reference the theorem name.